# How to create rpm package in yocto (poky) freescale linux

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

I am using Yocto(poky) freescale linux for creating new software. I have compiled my binaries for this system. But to build rpm package on this system I can not find rpmbuild command.

Do I need to use rpmbuild or opkg or anything else to create package on Yocto?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a bitbake recipe for your software. This recipe describes how that software is configured, built and packaged. If your target image is configured with rpm as a package manager, the result of executing that recipe will be an RPM file containing your software. See here: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0/dev-manual/dev-manual.html

Comment: Hi @Frank Meerkötter, Thank you very much for your help. I got the process explained on this link, but I can not find bitbake command on my version of Yocto. How can I install it?

Comment: @SwapnilMore how did you build your poky image when you don't used bitbake?!? Please clarify what you want. Do you want some software packaged and installed to your image? Or do you want to build a rpm package on your embedded platform? Or something completely different?

Comment: @g0hl1n I got fsl-image-full from other place. I am using Poky 1.6 daisy. And I want to build a rpm package on my embedded platform.  But I can not find bitbake command on my embedded platform.

Answer (score 0):

To add additional binaries or libraries for your project in Yocto,
you can add them in the recipes-extended/merger-files/merge directory.
Any files and directories copied to the "merge" directory will be copied
to the root filesystem created by Yocto.